# solve n which is an integer above 0 in python

Tags: python-3.x

This code works but it is not very efficient is there any help on a faster code in python to find n knowing that n is an integer above 0 and that n has no upper bound, how(x) will return you 1 if x>n, 0 if x = n, and -1 if x

```
def how(x):
    if x > n:
        return 1
    elif x < n:
        return -1
    else:
        return 0
def find(how):
    if how(1) == 1:
        return 1
    x = 2
    while how(x) != 1:
        x = x**x
    v = x
    while how(x) != 0:
        if how(x) ==  1:
            v = x
            x = (x+1)//2
        else:
            x += (v-x+1)//2
    return x
```

Comment: WHY do you name functions `how()` and parameters `how` the same - that is confusing. I dont get what this does. After looking 2 minutes at it, I feel as if i never _want_ to know what it does. The explaining text above it also makes no full sense - so maybe go over [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) again to maybe provide easier to understand and help-with questions.

Comment: Based on what you wrote the code fail to work.  I've fixed the code such that it runs/works. Not sure if I fixed it in the right direction, but good enough for you to explore . Thus, I've posted an answer with modified code and some print-statements so you can start exploring what you have made thus-far and get an understanding how to basic test your code as well (print-statements).

Answer (score 0):

Rebecca, I've added some print statements so you can see where goes what wrong. As Patrick Artner said... its a bit confusing which way to go so I've tried to clean-up some things that enable you to continue exploring comparison of two variables against each other (and fake error catching (0).

Lets start and remove the confusing lingo and produce something workable code. With current below script it runs and with **value = 1, reference = 1**  you get the below print result in a continues loop until YOU stop the script manually:

> v1 = n: error
>   loop1 1

```
def selector(v1, n):
    if v1 > n:
        print 'v1 > n', v1, n
        return 1
    elif v1 < n:
        print 'v1 < n', v1, n
        return -1
    else:
        print 'v1 == n: error'
        return 0

def find(value, reference):

    if selector(value, reference) == 1:
        return 1

    while selector(value, reference) != 1:

        x = value**value
        print 'loop1', x

    v = x

    while selector(value, reference) != 0:

        print 'loop2'

        if selector(value, reference) ==  1:
            v = value

            x = (value+1)/2

            print 'loop2-if', v, x
        else:
            x += (v-(value+1))/2
            print 'loop2-else', x

    print ' Almost done...' 
    return x

if __name__ == '__main__':

    n = 1
    print find(1, 1)
```

Happy exploring,....

Comment: Thanks I will take a look at it :)